В чем проблема данного кода?
Вот сам код.
import random

rand = random.randint(0, 1)
print(rand)
use = input("введите число: ")
if use == rand:
    print(1)

else:
    print(0)

По идее он должен записывать в переменную rand рандомное число и спрашивать у пользователя его число и записывать его в use и если rand = use выводить 1, а иначе 0. Но он всегда выводит 0. Вопрос почему

use = int(input("введите число: ")).

Потому что сравниваете число со строкой

Перевести строку в число можно функцией int
